# How can I connect my angular production build with my express api in docker?

Tags: angular, docker, express

Hey I have got an express api which sends an empty json object on localhost:3001/

I deployed the api on docker and it works.
Now I would like to access it from my angular application. But I got only the following Error:

[image]

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
setInterval(()=>{
  console.log("hier")
  this.http.get<any>(environment.wsExpress)
  .subscribe((data:any)=>{
    console.log(data)
  })
},1000)
```

}

environment.wsExpress points to http://backend:3001

Both of them are running in the same network "web". When I access the ngnix container and run curl http://backend:3001, I get the response.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16 As builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/homekit/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because your browser is the one doing the HTTP request not Nginx and your browser is not on the same network as the two containers. You have to use an IP address or a domain name of your server as your wsExpress env variable.